# Manipulating the value of p-value of output in R

Tags: r, p-value

Suppose

```
data11 <- c(0.5388417, 0.7263466, 0.3612457, 0.2495263, 0.1780413)
data22 <- c(0.674262245, 0.659560230, 0.001548212, 0.501228052, 0.802885484)
d=as.data.frame(cbind(dat=c(data11,data22),level=c(rep(1,length(data11)),rep(2,length(data22)))))
```

then, I use the function oneway_test to get tje p-value

```
library(coin)
oneway_test(d$dat~as.factor(d$level))
```

I get:

```
    Asymptotic Two-Sample Fisher-Pitman Permutation Test

data:  d$dat by as.factor(d$level) (1, 2)
Z = -0.70257, p-value = 0.4823
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

But, how can I save the value of P-value? . Try to do this: `d$p.value`. I do not get it

Thanks

Comment: Give the oneway_test object a name e.g. `p <- oneway_test(d$dat~as.factor(d$level))`. Call out the p-value with `pvalue(p)`

Comment: just a hint, to access the elements of S4 objects you use the slot operator `@` and not dollar operator `$`.

Comment: @albert Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation of the coin package.  You can use the pvalue function to return the pvalue:

```
results <- oneway_test(d$dat~as.factor(d$level))
pval <- pvalue(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not straighforward because the printed result (p-value) is not contained in the returned object of the function `oneway_test` but is printed as a side effect. You might use some regex as a workaround:

```
output <- oneway_test(d$dat~as.factor(d$level))

FindPValue = function(output){
  temp <- capture.output(output)
  return(as.numeric(gsub(".*p-value = ", "", temp[5])))
}

FindPValue(output)
#### [1] 0.4823
```

Thanks to Adam Quek for the advice with `capture.output`

Comment: OK i didn't know the pvalue function spotted by Adams... nice indeed and you get all the decimals for free

Comment: Nice function there though to due with most printed summary. You may want to use `capture.output` instead of sink, and add a `unlink("result_test.txt")` in your function to make it more seamless.